# Fonts family are not rendering correctly in HTML page , AngularJS application

Tags: html, css, angularjs, fonts, tinymce-4

In our AngularJS application, we are binding following HTML 'Description'(which is stored in Database) to DIV. This HTML code generates from TinyMCE editor.

```
<p>
<span style="font-family: tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Friday</span>
<span style="font-family: 'comic sans ms', sans-serif;">fever</span>!
</p>
```

In html page, we have written this code,

```
<div id="themeDiv"  ng-bind-html="Description"> </div>
```

But it is not showing applied fonts. Expected result is it needs to be displayed in proper font.

Comment: Which OS version doesn't render it correctly?

Comment: @31piy Windows 10, Google chrome